# mongoid $in: statement how do I ignore a field if the value is a blank array?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

So, I have a database of projects and im writing a search query. I want the user to be able to choose what fields they use or do not use, they are not required to fill them all in. Any fields the user ignores I dont want the query to be limited by what was not selected.

if a user skips `proposal_status:` in the html form I dont want the query to limit the search by a blank array. How would I alter my query to ignore the `proposal_status` line if `params[:status]` is a blank array?

```
Project.where(
  job_number: /#{params[:job_number]}/i,
  project_name: /#{params[:project_name]}/i,
  proposal_status: {:$in => params[:status] } # params[:status] == []
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two queries are equivalent:

```
Project.where(
  job_number: /#{params[:job_number]}/i,
  project_name: /#{params[:project_name]}/i,
  proposal_status: {:$in => params[:status] }
)

Project.where(job_number: /#{params[:job_number]}/i)
       .where(project_name: /#{params[:project_name]}/i)
       .where(proposal_status: {:$in => params[:status] })
```

If you build the query piece by piece then leaving out one piece is easy:

```
q = Project.where(job_number: /#{params[:job_number]}/i)
q = q.where(project_name: /#{params[:project_name]}/i)
q = q.where(proposal_status: {:$in => params[:status] }) if(params[:status].present?)
```

Also, Mongoid patches (or at least used to) some methods into `Symbol` so you could say:

```
where(:proposal_status.in => params[:status])
# --------------------^^^
```

to simplify things (unless they don't do this anymore of course).